# What it may mean: "to sip pop in a pop top can"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning, phrase-meaning

There's an Android game, "Sentence Master", which may be a fun for the language learners to play once in a while.  Of course, I'm not sure whether this game is a reliable app to further one's English with, but still, it's quite entertaining to be given a try.  To show what it's like, here's a picture:

[image: 1]

Today, I stumbled across this sentence which to me looks like sort of phonetic exercise:

> "Ben can sip pop in a pop top can."

I understand that Bob may be sipping some liquid from a can, but what's a pop and what's a pop top can, and why "in" it?

Comment: _Pop_ is a carbonated beverage, and [here](http://www.manujarvinen.com/~eternal/images/blogs/blender_aid/asset_library/misc/ref/can/6425514-beber-de-la-can.jpg) is a _pop top can!_

Comment: It's interesting how the sentence uses _can_ as both a modal verb and a noun, and _pop_ as a mass noun and a modifier. As for the preposition, I think _from_ would be a better choice than _in_, but it looks to me like the author wanted to cram in an extra word that ends with an ‘n’.

Comment: It sounds weird to this US English speaker to say that Ben sips pop **in** a pop-top can - yes, the pop is in the can, but we would normally say he sips **from** the can.  "In" makes it sound like Ben is in the can!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Pop" is term used for soda or other carbonated beverages in the Mid West United States.

A Pop Top can is really just a regular current generation soda can, specifically one that does not feature at removable tab.